# Nested array loses information when variable declared

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I have an array in json, composed of three other arrays. One of those three arrays also has another array nested in it, and that array has a third array nested within it:

```
{
    "items": [
        {location: "Tiberius' Palace", 
         starting_line: 0, 
         line_text: "I command sylyns, in þe peyn of forfetur,", 
         duration: 1, 
         characters: {first_character: 
                          {character: "Emperor", color: "660066"}
                     }
        }
    ],
    "directions": [],
    "locations": []
}
```

I feed this json into d3 in a pretty standard way:

```
d3.json("MM_chart_test.json", function(error, json)
```

and then call to each of the three arrays:

```
       var items = json.items;

       var locations = json.locations;

       var directions = json.stage_directions;
```

The problem I'm running into is that making these variable declarations results in the items variable dropping anything deeper than the characters declaration, so that the json looks like this:

```
{location: "Tiberius' Palace", 
 starting_line: 0, 
 line_text: "I command sylyns, in þe peyn of forfetur,", 
 duration: 1, 
 characters: {first_character: 
              null}
}
```

I haven't done anything beyond the variable declaration, and both of the other arrays work fine. It's obvious to me that the problem lies with declaring the variable, but I'm wondering what the best way is to do so without losing that two-deep information.  Thank you.

Comment: is the first_character property populated if you `console.log(json.items)`?

Comment: Your json isn't valid. Copy and paste in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @jeesh no, and that

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes around the property names. As [Sebastian Lorenzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741027/sebastian-lorenzo) said above it's invalid JSON.

```
{  
   "location":"Tiberius' Palace",
   "starting_line":0,
   "line_text":"I command sylyns, in þe peyn of forfetur,",
   "duration":1,
   "characters":{  
   "first_character":null
   }
}
```